# Blazor Pages displaying incorrectly in production mode

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a Blazor .net 7 webpage project tin visual studio 2022. When running the executable from the Visual studio environment in a Development profile (in launchsettings.json) everything works as expected.

However, once I change this to “Production”, while keeping everything else the same, the pages do not render correctly. The navigation menu is missing and the rest of the page looks more basic.

I suspect that it cannot see the CSS and other pages and this is causing the problem, however this is just my guess.

I've included a copy of the profiles below, the profile one works correctly, and the profile production one causes the error.

```
"profiles": {
  "Project": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "dotnetRunMessages": true,
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7254;http://localhost:5254",
    "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
  },
  "Project-Production": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "dotnetRunMessages": true,
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7254;http://localhost:5254",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the relevant code for creating the web application:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Logging.AddLog4Net();
// Add services to the container.
Configure(builder.Services);
var app = builder.Build();
ConfigureApp(app);
app.RunAsync();

private static void Configure(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddHttpClient();
    services.AddMudServices();
    services.AddScoped<DialogService>();
    services.AddScoped<NotificationService>();
    services.AddScoped<TooltipService>();
    services.AddScoped<ContextMenuService>();
}

private static void ConfigureApp(WebApplication app)
{
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.MapBlazorHub();
    app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
}
```

I'm fairly new to programming with web projects, so I imagine that it's something fairly basic that I have missed, but I cannot seem to find it! I have checked other posts on Stack overflow and couldn't find anything that has helped me.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: start with a Ctrl+F5

Comment: Exactly the same result

Comment: And what does the network tab show?  Any 404s ?

Comment: Trying to check, it appears the network diagnostic tool has been removed from VS 2022 (community edition at least). Wireshark isn't helping me as its HTTPS traffic. I'll try and find another way to see

Comment: Is chrome loading the css file?  That's where you should be checking file activity-- in your client browser.  Are you using css isolation?  Did you remember to upload your wwwroot folder files?  Did you use a local file path (like localhost) that is now broken with your website name in it?  If you're on an IIS server, did you check folder permissions?

Comment: Ok Looked at the firefox developer console. Appears the Styles.css, Mudblazor.min.css, Mublazor.min.js are not found.

Comment: @bennyboy1973 So appears CSS files are not being found. So I've been trying to run this as a standalone application, where would I upload the wwwroot files?

Comment: Oh wait I think I misunderstood your question.  You're not deploying it, just trying to get it to run in Release mode, right?

Comment: I was trying to get it ready for deployment, but at the moment I am trying to get it to work in production mode rather than development environment, before I go for a deployment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after the helpful prompts from @henk and @bennyboy1973, the issue was that some css and js files were not being found and therefore causing issues.

Bit of research located this blog:
https://dev.to/j_sakamoto/how-to-deal-with-the-http-404-content-foo-bar-css-not-found-when-using-razor-component-package-on-asp-net-core-blazor-app-aai

The issue appears to be that StaticWebAssetsFileProvider is only used in Development mode and not in Production.

The blog above provides some code, which I modified into the following code and fixed the issue:

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, cb) =>
{
    if (!ctx.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(
      ctx.HostingEnvironment,
      ctx.Configuration);
    }
}
);
```

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: good work.  Remember to set the question to answer when it unlocks for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I ran into the same issue and this fixed it